# Angularjs how to return multi variables

Tags: angularjs, model

Starting to learn angularjs I'm trying some simple examples.
I want in my view 2 variables total1 en total2, which are calculated in a function in my js.

my js

```
    var total1 = 0;
    var total2 = 0; 

    // Use the angular forEach helper method to
    // loop through the services array:

    angular.forEach($scope.services, function(s){
        if (s.active){
            total1+= s.price;
            total2+= 1;
        }
    });

    return [total1, total2];
};
```

my html

```
        <div class="total">

            <!-- Calculate the total price of all chosen services. Format it as currency. -->
            Totaal: <span>{{total1 | currency:"€ "}}</span>
            Selected: <span>{{total2 | currency:"€ "}}</span>
        </div>
```

Is there a way to show the variables in the view withing angular, using somehing like the {{my_var1}}  {{my_var2}}

Comment: Why you need to return those variables?? Attach those variables to $scope and you can access it in your view

Comment: Replace var total1 = 0 with $scope.total1 = 0, and do $scope.total1 += s.price. Do the same with total2.

Comment: Thank you for these answers. I got it (kind of) work now  http://jsfiddle.net/richard7/BLJ5M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to expose your variables as fields in your scope.

```
$scope.total1 = 0;
$scope.total2 = 0;
```

That should suffice, no need to return anything.